# Finding current in the circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

Hi anyone. I try to de-draw the circuit in the simpler to calculate i1 and i2. But can not. Anyone have any hint to do this question ? . 
Or just give me the specific name of the way of how to do that. :( thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use kirchoff's loop and junction law. :)

Answer (score 1):

The total resistance seen by the voltage source is:
$$
R_{tot}=[(6//12)+(12//6)]\Omega = 8\Omega
$$
then:
$$
i_1=\frac{20V}{8\Omega}=2.5A
$$

Now let's calculate the voltage of the intermediate node, i.e. the node where you measure $i_2$:
$$
V_{mid}=20V\frac{12//6}{(12//6)+(12//6)}=20V\times\frac12=10V
$$
The current $i_2$ can be computed as the current in the top $6\Omega$ resistor minus the current in the bottom $12\Omega$ resistor, i.e.:

$$
i_2 = \frac{10V}{6\Omega} - \frac{10V}{12\Omega} = 833mA
$$

and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

try re-drawing it like this:

[image]

then work out the total resistance in the circuit and use V-IR to calculate i1. then find the percentage of current goung through each branch of the wire.